# MissingMethodException FileExistenceCache with MVC 5.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to upgrade from MVC 5.0 to MVC 5.1.

In my global.asax i have the following line :

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new WebSiteViewEngine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ModulesPath"]));
```

The first line throw an exception 
System.MissingMethodException:
Méthod not found : 'Void System.Web.WebPages.FileExistenceCache..ctor(System.Func`1, Int32)'.

In my web config

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />       
 </appSettings>  

<runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="modules/bin" />
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Unity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>            
        </assemblyBinding> 
    </runtime>
```

i'm using System.web.mvc 5.1.20129.0
System.Web.WebPage 3.0.20129.0

any ideas why this error occured ?

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced same issue and after hell lot of search and trial and error, I have resolve this issue.

**Error:**

> The type initializer for 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines' threw an
>   exception.

**StackTrace:**

> System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233036   Message=The type initializer for
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines' threw an exception.
>   Source=System.Web.Mvc   TypeName=System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines.get_Engines()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.get_ViewEngineCollection()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View(String viewName, String masterName, Object model)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View()
>          at C3PO.Web.Controllers.UserController.Index() in d:\Pallavi\C3PO\3CPO\Source
>   Code\C3PO\C3PO.Web\Controllers\UserController.cs:line 39
>          at C3PO.Test.HomeControllerTest.TestExtensionView() in d:\Pallavi\C3PO\3CPO\Source Code\C3PO\C3PO.Test\UnitTest1.cs:line 71
>   InnerException: System.MissingMethodException
>          HResult=-2146233069
>          Message=Method not found: 'Void System.Web.WebPages.FileExistenceCache..ctor(System.Func`1<System.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathProvider>,
>   Int32)'.
>          Source=System.Web.Mvc
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine..ctor(IViewPageActivator
>   viewPageActivator, IResolver`1 activatorResolver, IDependencyResolver
>   dependencyResolver, VirtualPathProvider pathProvider)
>               at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine..ctor(IViewPageActivator
>   viewPageActivator)
>               at System.Web.Mvc.WebFormViewEngine..ctor(IViewPageActivator
>   viewPageActivator)
>               at System.Web.Mvc.WebFormViewEngine..ctor()
>               at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines..cctor()
>          InnerException:

**Conclusion:**

I found that its issue with `System.Web.Mvc` version 5.1 and above.
I have changed it to use `System.Web.Mvc 5`, and everything is working fine now.